# Understanding problem: How to add a stylesheet to a web part

Tags: web-part, css, cssregistration

Well, I try to add a css stylesheet to my web part but it didn’t work… I read that there are many ways to a css file into a web part, but I didn’t understand them….

First I installed the Sharepoint 2010 Tools, to create a visual web part for sandboxing. 
After that I created an empty project and added a visual web part (sandbox) to the project.
Just after that, I created a new folder in the visual web part and added the stylesheet file to them.

Now I will add this css file to my web part, but I don’t know how…

I read, that this I possible with:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" Name="./Styles/Site.css" />
```

But Visual Studio tells me, that an assembly for `::Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.CssRegistration` is missing.

I use also use `using Microsoft.SharePoint`;

What is the best way, to import a css file to a web part? The css file should just available for this web part.

It would be awesome, if someone could help me to understand, how to include a stylesheet.

**Information:
CssRegistration: Available in Sandboxed Solutions: No!**

Greetz

Comment: Make sure an Assembly directive appears at the top of the ASCX page, that points to the Microsoft.SharePoint assembly, and that the SharePoint TagPrefix points to this assembly.

Comment: Okay. If i add `<SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" Name="./Styles/Site.css" />` in the .ascx file, some code will automatically added to the .ascx.gcs file. Must i add the `Microsoft.SharePoint` assembly to the .ascx file? At the moment, the assembly is in the .ascx.gcs file.

Comment: Can't quite remember how the plugin generates the ascx.g.cs file, but try manually adding the Assembly directive to the .ascx file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method to add the CSS is to create the CssRegistration object in the C# codebehind for the web part, and add your instance of CssRegistration to the web part's control hierarchy using `this.ChildControls.Add()`.

You'll need to ensure this code is done within CreateChildControls override of the web part.

Comment: In the ascx.g.cs file the some `CssRegistration` code will add automatically. And here Visual Studio tells me, that a assembly is missing. This is the code:`private global::Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.CssRegistration @__BuildControl__control2() {
            global::Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.CssRegistration @__ctrl;
            @__ctrl = new global::Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.CssRegistration();
            @__ctrl.Name = "./Styles/Site.css";
            return @__ctrl;
}`

Comment: Like I said in the comment thread above, try adding the SharePoint Assembly to the Assembly ASP.NET Directive at the top of the ascx file.

Comment: Okay, atm i haven't access to the development pc. Do u mean something like `<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>` in the ascx.

Comment: Exactly that, yeah. Though it might need a fully qualified assembly name (including the Version, Culture and Public Key Token).

Comment: Okay, i will test it tomorrow. But why i get the assembly warning message in the ascx.g.cs file, that's strange... In the the ascx.g.cs file i use the Microsoft.SharePoint assembly. Will will let u know if it's work. So far many thanks!

Comment: Okay, i have added the assembly to the ascx fiel, but it didn't work! I have created a new project as visual webpart without sandboxing and added `<SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" Name="./Styles/Site.css" />` here the css file work very well. Is it possible, that i can't include a css file in a sandbox project? Greetz

Comment: You can most certainly add a CSS file in the sandbox. However, you can only provision it to a library via a Module, and you must access it regardless of site collection you are in. Hence the suggestion for creating the CssRegistration in the C# code, and using the ServerRelativeUrl to the site collection to get the full path to the CSS file.

Comment: Mhm, im a little bit confused :). You said i could include css files with CssRegistration in the C# code. But in MSDN Microsift wrote: Available in Sandboxed Solutions: No. I think for the beginning, i will use just a normal visual webpart... I did not get it working... Thats very strange stuff:)

Comment: Apologies, I thought CssReg was sandboxable! That's the source of your problem then :) Elsewise, you can just put a normal `<link href...` in your sandboxed visual web part ASCX markup.

Comment: It's so annoying how to include a damn css file into a web part... Now i had it included with `<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Styles/Site.css" />`. In VS the css files would be recognise, everything looks fine. But how could i deploy them to sharepoint? If i use any deployment i cant build the project... :(

Comment: You need to read this for instructions on deploying files using VS2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441170.aspx

Comment: Okay, after a break, i did it. Now the css style works fine. I added a module and insert into the xml file: `<Module Name="Style Library">
    <File Path="Style Library\Styles\Button.css" Url="Style Library/Styles/Button.css" />
    <File Path="Style Library\Styles\Site.css" Url="Style Library/Styles/Site.css" />
  </Module>`. After that I could insert the css with: `<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://<Servername>/Style Library/Styles/Button.css" />`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you also will need to add JS code, consider using the ScriptManager. See my answer on that topic [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/how-to-use-javascript-and-css-in-a-web-part)

Comment: Merci. That would be the next step. The asp and c# code is ready, just the css and js are missing. I will give you tomorrow feedback if every think works fine. Thanks!

Comment: of course this is **not** a Sandboxed solution, isn't it?